# NSURLSessionDownloadTask switching from http to https

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have an `AFHTTPSessionManager` created `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` being used to download a video within an app that *sometimes* when initialized with an http:80 url will convert it to https:443.  This is happening before any connection attempt is being made (I added a custom HTTP protocol class via `NSURLSessionConfiguration` to the session in order to log when the connection is being made).

By the time the request makes it to the

```
-(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

delegate method of my CustomHTTPProtocolDelegate class, the request has been changed to https.

App Transport Security is disabled (`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads=true`) and this behavior seems to be associated with a particular http-only server (other http-only server have no issue, and the connection is made as http on port 80).

Any idea of what could be going on? Anything else I could do to debug?

Here is how the download task is being created (including the debug custom protocol class):

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];
    config.protocolClasses = @[[CustomHTTPProtocol class]];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *session = [[AFHTTPSessionManager manager] initWithSessionConfiguration:config];

    self.downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithRequest:request  progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response){
```

...

[UPDATE]
This issue is causing us a number of headaches, so to help facilitate troubleshooting, I created a small test project to help narrow in on the problem.  My simple project does two things, loads a url into a UIWebView and downloads a file using NSURLSessionDownloadTask.  The urls for these actions follow this pattern:
WebView URL: https://console.company.com/home.html
Download URL: http://data.company.com/file.txt
And those hostnames resolve to different IPs (different servers).

If I download the file before navigating the webview, then everything is fine, but if the webview loads its URL first, then the download URL will be switched to HTTPS automatically and the initial request for data will fail.  One thought we had was that once iOS opens a TLS tunnel for the HTTPS connection that the webview is creating, that it tries to use that same tunnel for all subsequent *.company.com connections.  Or at the very least, it assumes all *.company.com connections must also be TLS.

Comment: Is it possible the server enforces https? Or maybe a HSTS max-time issue? Also, have you tried what happens if you don't use AFNetworking but a regular iOS session? I'm not sure, but perhaps the latest version of AFNetworking does some smart shenanigans (unlikely, but I didn't check)? HHTPS is a good thing (so I guess it's clear you should just use it if your server supports it), but that's probably besides the question.

Comment: The server does not support https at all; http-only content server, and it cannot be switched to use https.  I have reimplemented it using NSURLSession instead of AFNetworking, but I get the same behavior.  Also, as far as I can tell the switch from http to https is happening prior to the request going out over the network.  Something in the bowels of CoreFoundation.

Comment: Are you able to get any data from your API call?

Comment: No data, the server refuses the https connection.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Both servers were sending a [HSTS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) for all subdomains.  Because the networking layer under NSURLSession observes this header, the calls to the HTTP server were being upgraded to HTTPS prior to leaving the client.